# Setting the style in ItemContainerStyleSelector based on the property value present in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to know Can u decide the style in custom Style Selector class based on Property value present in the corresponding ViewModel??

Or

Is there any way to select the ItemContainerstyle based on the Property in the ViewModel??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `ItemsControl` provides `ItemContainerStyleSelector` for this. There could be two different scenarios for choosing `Style` for `ItemContainer`.

In this example, we have

```
public class ViewModel
{ 
   public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; } 
   public bool IsGood { get; set; }
}
```

1. Choosing based on main ViewModel (this is different from `ItemsSource`). Use `Trigger` for this.

   ```
      <ItemsControl.Style>
           <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
               <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsGood}" Value="True">
                       <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource Style1Key}"/>
                   </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
      </ItemsControl.Style>
   ```
2. Choosing based on a property (ex, Name) of `Student`. We have to use `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyleSelector` here.

   ```
     public class MyStyleSelector : StyleSelector
       {
           public Style Style1 { get; set; }
           public Style Style2 { get; set; }

           public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
           {
               Student s = (Student)item;
               if(s.Name == "Gopi")
                   return Style1;
               else
                   return Style2;
           }
       }
   ```

   XAML

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
       <Style x:Key="Style1Key">
           <Setter Property="Control.Opacity" Value="0.3"/>
       </Style>
       <Style x:Key="Style2Key">
           <Setter Property="Control.Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
       </Style>
   </Window.Resources> 
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
   ...
     <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
        <local:MyStyleSelector Style1="{StaticResource Style1Key}" Style2="{StaticResource Style2Key}"/>
     </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyleSelector>  
   ...
   </ItemsControl>
   ```