# In a tree view with multiple DataTemplates, how to apply a style to only one of them

Tags: wpf, treeview, datatemplate

I have a `TreeView` control that shows different tyeps of objects. I use multiple DataTemplates, one per type, with their `DataType` set accordingly.
Code:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Family}" ItemsSource = "Members">
            <!-- template omitted here-->
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type local:FamilyMember}">
            <!--template omitted-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Now I want to apply a style to the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and only to it. I must use a style because I set a few properties of the `TreeViewItem`, which is in this case the items container.
I tried:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Family}" ItemsSource = "Members">
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType = "TreeViewItem">
            <!-- some styling of the tree view item-->
        </Style>
    <\HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsContainerStyle>
    <!-- template omitted here-->
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

but the style gets applied to all tree items, even those presenting `FamilyMember` objects, which are not of the same template.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ItemContainerStyleSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyleselector(v=vs.110).aspx) property to control which styles get applied to which items. I found an example usage in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38611369/4934541) that might help you get started. The main difference from that example is that you would base your selection on the type of the object rather than a property of the object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there a way to do it in plain XAML?

Comment: Nothing I can think of would be XAML only. However, you could probably develop a generic enough style selector class mapping types to styles if you spent some time on it. Then, you could reuse it everywhere and do the work in XAML only. I have never tried it myself.

Comment: I tried it, and it solved the problem. But now for a strange reason I get a lot of binding errors in output window, saying that `FamilyMember`has no member with name `Members`. Seems like it tries to apply the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to family members too, even with `DataType` set to `Family`. What to do now?

Comment: I am not sure what is happening. There may be an error somewhere in your style selector or your XAML. Perhaps you could update your question with what you have now?

Comment: I posted a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806867/itemcontainerstyleselector-causes-binding-errors). Thanks for your help, and further help will be appreciated.